# Liferay get browser URL

Tags: liferay-6.2

I have a HttpServletRequest object with me in a post login hook. How to get what URL is there is the browser.

When I am using PortalUtil.getCurrentCompleteURL(HttpServletRequest) I am always getting http://localhost:8080/c. I need something like http://localhost:8080/web/abc.

I don't have ThemeDisplay object with me.

Comment: did you try PortalUtil.getCurrentURL(myRequest);

Comment: @Issamovitch that gives me /c

Comment: i think your example should work : HttpServletRequest servletRequest = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request);
        String currentCompleteUrl = PortalUtil.getCurrentCompleteURL(servletRequest);

Comment: @Issamovitch I am already having HttpServletRequest. So i dont need that from PortalUtil. PortalUtil.getCurrentCompleteURL(servletRequest); is giving me http://localhost:8080/c

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the URL you are looking for is the one from before the login. The portal saves that one in the session when redirecting to the login page. You can access it like this:

```
String lastPath = session.getAttribute(WebKeys.LAST_PATH);
```